# ¿Cómo puedo agregar filas a una tabla dinámicamente con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom

He creado una función que selecciona una imagen, obteniendo su url, texto alternativo y tamaño.

Necesito agregar a una tabla esos datos. En el HTML tengo un `<tbdody>` donde tengo que ir poniendo los `<tr>`y `<td>` correspondientes.

Son 3 campos como he dicho: URL, texto alternativo y dimensiones, y cada vez que ejecute la función e introduzca el número de imagen que quiero seleccionar, deben ir agregándose los datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para cada imagen del documento estoy creando una nueva fila a la tabla `data`. Para cada atributo estoy creando una nueva casilla `td` dentro de la fila

Espero que esto es lo que preguntabas

```js
//todas las imágenes del documento
let images = document.querySelectorAll("img");
//para cada imagen
images.forEach(img=>{
  //recupera el valor de los atributos
  let attrs = [
    img.getAttribute("src"),
    img.getAttribute("alt"),
    img.getAttribute("width"),
    img.getAttribute("height")
  ]
  // crea un nuevo elemento te
  let tr = document.createElement("tr");
  
  //para cada atributo de la imagen crea un nuevo elemento td cuyo innerHTML es el valor del atributo
  for(let i = 0; i < attrs.length; i++ ){
    let td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = attrs[i];
    //agrega el td al tr
    tr.appendChild(td);
  }
  
  //agrega el tr a la tabla
  data.appendChild(tr)
});
```

```css
table{border-collapse:collapse;}
td{border:1px solid; padding:.5em;}
```

```html
<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/imgres.jpg" alt="El grito de Munch" width="200" height="252" />
<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/darwin300.jpg" alt="Mi perro Darwin" width="200" height="200"/>

<table id="data">
  <tr>
    <td>src</td>
    <td>alt</td>
    <td>width</td>
    <td>height</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Eso era, muchísimas gracias!!!